# HTML form is causing unwanted margin (CSS)

Tags: html, css

So without the form my bottom bar is touching the end of the vertical lines. When I add the HTML for the search bar it causes the horizontal line to shift down. I cant figure out how to move the seach bar so that it's in line with the the other words. I've tried using padding, margins, positive, and negative pixels to move the search bar, but nothing works. Below are the three blocks that have effects on the div the form is in.

```
#search-bar {       
  top: 0px;
}

.topbar {
  float: left;
  height: 150%;
}

#top-bar {
  width:1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add the html or a fiddle, as well, if you want valuable assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
position: fixed;
```

Further, if you want the search bar to be flush against the let hand side, use

`left: 0px;`

For bottom, use `bottom: 0px;`

Top: `top: 0px;` etc

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: But : 1- how could your understand the question and 2- why do you reffer to w3schools instead of w3c specs ?

Comment: @MilchePatern. Your Nr 1 does not makes sense. Please use proper English. 2) It is my answer and I can refer to which site I want. Is this just a random nonsense comment as an attempt to up your rank? Please comment something of value

Comment: thank you for trying however when I have the position: fixed; the search bar doesn't go where I want and when I move it over, my vertical lines dont work for it. I will keep trying.